# Cropper Plugin How to get uploaded image resolution

Tags: jquery

Using cropper plugin,

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

How to get uploaded image resolution before it's being cropped, to display a message.

Thanks

Comment: You at least should add some code, we are here to help not to write your code, in the GIT you have a lot information about the plug in and here you have a good start https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: too much info.. if you not able to help just leave. thanks